# Factor the trinomial, James Stewart Precalculus $1.3$, exercise $76$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck and have no idea how to proceed with factoring of the given trinomial.

$$2(a+b)^2 + 5(a+b) - 3$$

I tried expanding it like that but I can't see any pattern that would help me to proceed further.

$$2(a+b)^2 + 5(a+b) - 3 = 2a^2 + 4ab + b^2 + 5a + 5b - 3$$

$$2(a+b)^2 + 5(a+b) - 3 = (a + b)(2(a+b) + 5) - 3$$

This is exercise number $76$, chapter $1.3$, from James Stewart's precalculus book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Reduce to a simpler problem by setting $x:=a+b$. Now you're left with factoring $2x^2+5x -3$. Once you've done that, substitute back $x=a+b$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x \ for\ a+b$,  so the equation $2(a+b)^2 + 5(a+b) - 3$ becomes $2x^2+5x-3$. Now Solve for $2x^2+5x-3$. \begin{align}
2x^2+5x-3\\ =2x^2+6x-x-3\\=2x(x-3)-1(x-3)\\ =(2x-1)(x-3) \end{align} and now substitute $x=a+b $ again to get $[2(a+b)-1](a+b-3)$.